# how to decrease jrxml band detail height dynamically

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

I have a band with 2 list element based. If both list have data PDF generated properly but if 1 list is empty band height doesn't decrease and places white blanks in PDF.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="liberty_new_bill_format" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="571" leftMargin="12" rightMargin="12" topMargin="12" bottomMargin="12" uuid="b6691099-6e36-4db6-a00d-f7d0d2167bd6">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<subDataset name="LW_IDD_CALL" uuid="48484a78-7d0d-4b22-86bd-9ebd1daac462">
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Projects\\BE5.0.0\\repository\\Bill Export Format\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="ID_USERNAME" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/custominfo/multiplerecord[@type="LW_CALL_DETAIL"]/record]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CALLDATETIME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@CALLDATETIME]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CALLSECTION" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@CALLSECTION]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CALLTYPE" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@CALLTYPE]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="COUNTRY" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@COUNTRY]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="DURATIONMIN" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@DURATIONMIN]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="DURATIONSEC" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@DURATIONSEC]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="PHONENO" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@PHONENO]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="RATE" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@RATE]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="REFUNDEXISTS" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@REFUNDEXISTS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="USAGEKB" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@USAGEKB]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="USAGEMB" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@USAGEMB]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="USAGEAMOUNT" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@USAGEAMOUNT]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="LWFORMATPATTERN" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/custominfo/singlerecord/@LWFORMATPATTERN]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="LWMINORUNIT" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/custominfo/singlerecord/@LWMINORUNIT]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="CDR_COUNT" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None" calculation="Count">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{CALLSECTION}.equals("VOICEIDD")]]></filterExpression>
</subDataset>
<subDataset name="LW_IDD_GLOBAL_SMS" uuid="428c32be-39c8-425e-ba21-10f73f94cdbf">
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Projects\\BE5.0.0\\repository\\Bill Export Format\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="ID_USERNAME" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/custominfo/multiplerecord[@type="LW_CALL_DETAIL"]/record]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="LWMINORUNIT" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/custominfo/singlerecord/@LWMINORUNIT]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="LWFORMATPATTERN" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/custominfo/singlerecord/@LWFORMATPATTERN]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CALLDATETIME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@CALLDATETIME]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CALLSECTION" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@CALLSECTION]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CALLTYPE" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@CALLTYPE]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="COUNTRY" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@COUNTRY]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="DURATIONMIN" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@DURATIONMIN]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="DURATIONSEC" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@DURATIONSEC]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="PHONENO" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@PHONENO]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="RATE" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@RATE]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="REFUNDEXISTS" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@REFUNDEXISTS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="USAGEKB" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@USAGEKB]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="USAGEMB" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@USAGEMB]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="USAGEAMOUNT" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@USAGEAMOUNT]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="CDR_COUNT" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None" calculation="Count">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{CALLSECTION}.equals("SMSIDD")]]></filterExpression>
</subDataset>
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/custominfo]]>
</queryString>
<field name="LWFORMATPATTERN" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[singlerecord/@LWFORMATPATTERN]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="LWMINORUNIT" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[singlerecord/@LWMINORUNIT]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="SMSIDDAMOUNT" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[singlerecord/@SMSIDDAMOUNT]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="VOICEIDDAMOUNT" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[singlerecord/@VOICEIDDAMOUNT]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<variable name="IDD_AMOUNT_SUM" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[Double.parseDouble($F{VOICEIDDAMOUNT}.replace( " ", "0" )) + Double.parseDouble($F{SMSIDDAMOUNT}.replace( " ", "0" ))]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="182" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="26" y="12" width="515" height="170" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7cb21acd-38f6-4987-9ae9-a5957b70f88c"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
            </box>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="515" height="27" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#F0F0F0" uuid="7a36219e-de1d-461c-b90b-b0ce10791200"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="6" y="0" width="116" height="27" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="afa2f370-fd5f-490f-9c62-7ce5ecbe86bd"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans Extrabold" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Data]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="515" height="57" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3b661c38-6d27-441e-b137-c2054790863d">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Double.parseDouble($F{VOICEIDDAMOUNT}.replace( " ", "0" )) > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="325" y="21" width="60" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d89d85f3-6c4e-4033-9bdd-0d3eb4da5017"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Phone #]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="7" y="21" width="100" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="b086e195-0b0b-4d64-9545-1deb2ca5f10f"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Date & Time]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="37" width="515" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f19ffb57-efe4-4c20-84f8-2b0de599a0e3"/>
                    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="LW_IDD_CALL" uuid="247b3030-df73-4c6a-9ca8-3ada738c308f">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)
                    $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/custominfo/multiplerecord[@type='LW_CALL_DETAIL']/record")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:listContents height="20" width="515">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="7" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="0f79a5c5-2964-481c-9192-963b630d05c7"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CALLDATETIME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="402" y="0" width="46" height="20" uuid="92bc22ad-6a29-4e3b-858d-261755960bbb"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["$" + new DecimalFormat($F{LWFORMATPATTERN}).format((Double.parseDouble($F{RATE}.replace( " ", "0" ))/java.lang.Math.pow( 10,new java.lang.Double($F{LWMINORUNIT})))) + "/min"]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="465" y="0" width="45" height="20" uuid="4cdad71e-93f6-4692-9bec-3eb427551e5c"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["$" + new DecimalFormat($F{LWFORMATPATTERN}).format((Double.parseDouble($F{USAGEAMOUNT}.replace( " ", "0" ))/java.lang.Math.pow( 10,new java.lang.Double($F{LWMINORUNIT}))))]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="325" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="a4ec29dd-a2ee-47f6-a042-9070b29edaff"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PHONENO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="170" y="0" width="110" height="20" uuid="1ff085d3-3a74-402b-adf1-254d26dd87eb"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNTRY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="8f7f0b18-8d85-42fe-9078-aac4db6834cb"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new DecimalFormat("#,##00").format((Double.parseDouble($F{DURATIONMIN}.replace( " ", "0" )))) + ":" +new DecimalFormat("#,##00").format((Double.parseDouble($F{DURATIONSEC}.replace( " ", "0" ))))]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:listContents>
                    </jr:list>
                </componentElement>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="401" y="21" width="46" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="384a4fa0-f294-4f52-9f6e-80ca0570ceff"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Rate]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="110" y="21" width="50" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d7fc4734-c8e4-4aaf-9ff4-bc1638a6f5a5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Duration]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="170" y="21" width="110" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="16ff4b2c-8087-4f52-8533-12d8f15263d7"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Country]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="465" y="21" width="45" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a023ec4d-97aa-4a40-8408-673e5d4f726d"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="7" y="0" width="116" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0e87bb45-f29a-4a50-b9d1-846f1d7ae575"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[IDD Calls]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="100" width="515" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="0ccd7e2c-e134-4964-8b57-38fdd6ae78d3">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Double.parseDouble($F{VOICEIDDAMOUNT}.replace( " ", "0" )) > 0 && Double.parseDouble($F{SMSIDDAMOUNT}.replace( " ", "0" )) > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="12" y="5" width="491" height="1" uuid="fab0c382-b32d-4809-8078-668a82dd86eb"/>
                </line>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="115" width="515" height="55" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="215cc558-db31-40ab-ba16-50b0d7b3b77a">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Double.parseDouble($F{SMSIDDAMOUNT}.replace( " ", "0" )) > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="324" y="21" width="60" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a67a56df-8e16-45e5-88fa-91c9e4a26063"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Phone #]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="7" y="21" width="100" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="ec0e8108-c5e4-45c0-ba77-1b8f3373ac9e"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Date & Time]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="36" width="515" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="785a5bd6-9654-4f46-aed3-d6c0d9b8a10c"/>
                    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="LW_IDD_GLOBAL_SMS" uuid="0ed48425-e6d9-43c5-bc52-d117944c13a6">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)
                    $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/custominfo/multiplerecord[@type='LW_CALL_DETAIL']/record")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:listContents height="18" width="515">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="7" y="0" width="100" height="18" uuid="0744b38a-7fe9-4b59-82d0-28779b2136bb"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CALLDATETIME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="465" y="0" width="45" height="18" uuid="4352e775-ad18-4207-a28b-01c828971608"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["$" + new DecimalFormat($F{LWFORMATPATTERN}).format((Double.parseDouble($F{USAGEAMOUNT}.replace( " ", "0" ))/java.lang.Math.pow( 10,new java.lang.Double($F{LWMINORUNIT}))))]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="325" y="0" width="60" height="18" uuid="be557830-7c4c-4125-a14a-a341cf8b1499"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PHONENO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="170" y="0" width="110" height="18" uuid="06bc7ad5-5d31-4143-9525-12dedb210239"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNTRY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:listContents>
                    </jr:list>
                </componentElement>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="465" y="21" width="45" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a758b1c2-29f7-4d18-af29-e262330fff2c"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="170" y="21" width="110" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="367c8854-61db-4320-8712-508366f66bfa"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Country]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="6" y="0" width="116" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="774c12ff-1e22-42d1-adb7-4493b49f10e1"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Global SMS]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </frame>
    </band>
    <band height="119">
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="26" y="22" width="515" height="85" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9b01e260-764e-460d-9741-d2f0ae1216f3"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
            </box>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="515" height="27" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#F0F0F0" uuid="1b389123-b4b6-446b-abd1-67185b88eaf8"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="6" y="0" width="116" height="27" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d3813577-f9cd-478b-9604-0416ef46254b"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Open Sans Extrabold" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Charges]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="46" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
```

We are using xml data source for this.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?><custominfo><singlerecord ACCOUNTNAME="BHADRINATH RAMACHANDRAN" ACCOUNTNUMBER="LW555358" ACCOUNTTYPEID="ACT06" ADDONDATAAMOUNT="600" ADDONDATAQUOTA="1" ADDONSMSAMOUNT="0" ADDONSMSQUOTA="0" ADDONVOICEAMOUNT="0" ADDONVOICEQUOTA="0" ADDRESS="Liberty Wireless  #221  Henderson Road, #06-04 Singapore 310231" ADDRESS1="Liberty Wireless  #221  Henderson Road, #06-04" ADDRESS2="Liberty Wireless, #221, Henderson Road;06;04;" ADDRESSTYPEID="ADT02" ADJUSTMENT="0" ADJUSTMENTAMOUNT="0" ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT="0" ADVANCEPAYMENTAMOUNT="0" ADVANCEPERIOD="01-31 May 2017" ADVANCE_PAYAMOUNT="0" ADVANCE_PAYAMOUNT_DATE="" ADV_FROMDATE="01 May 2017" ADV_TODATE="31 May 2017" ALIAS="SGD" AUTOBOOSTAMOUNT="0" AUTOBOOSTDATAUSED="0" AUTOBOOSTQUOTA="0" AUTO_BOOST_DATA="0" AUTO_BOOST_USAGE="0" AUTO_TOPUP_AMOUNT="0" BASEAMOUNT="2800" BASEDATAQUOTA="3" BASEDATAUSED="2.6" BASESMSQUOTA="0" BASEVOICEQUOTA="100" BASE_AMOUNT="2800" BASE_COMPONENT_DATA_VOLUME="8.25" BASE_DATA_VOLUME="3" BASE_SMS_COUNT="0" BASE_USAGE="2.54" BASE_VOICE_MIN="0" BILLAMOUNT="4205" BILLDATE="01 May 2017" BILLINGAREANAME="Default" BILLPERIOD="01-30 Apr 2017" BONUSDATAUSED="4.2" BONUSQUOTA="3.1" BONUS_DATA="4348" BONUS_USAGE="4340" BOOSTAMOUNT="0" BOOSTDATAUSED="0" BOOSTQUOTA="0" BOOST_DATA="0" BOOST_ONLY_AMOUNT="0" BOOST_USAGE="0" CIRCLECREDITAMOUNT="0" CITYNAME="Singapore" COMPONENT_AMOUNT="600" COMPONENT_DATA_AMOUNT="600" COMPONENT_DATA_VOLUME="1" COMPONENT_SMS_AMOUNT="0" COMPONENT_SMS_COUNT="0" COMPONENT_VOICE_AMOUNT="0" COMPONENT_VOICE_MIN="0" COUNTRYNAME="Singapore" CREATEDATE="27 Apr 2017" CURRENCYNAME=" " CURRENTBILLCHARGE="4205" CURR_BASE_DATA_VOLUME="3" CURR_BASE_SMS_COUNT="0" CURR_BASE_VOICE_MIN="100" CURR_BONUS_DATA="3.1" CURR_COMPONENT_DATA_VOLUME="1" CURR_COMPONENT_SMS_COUNT="0" CURR_COMPONENT_VOICE_MIN="0" DATAROAMAMOUNT="0" DATA_ROAMING_AMOUNT="0" DEBITDOCUMENTID="DBD000702898" DEBITDOCUMENTNUMBER="REG0000001377872" DEBITPAYMENTAMOUNT="4525" DEBIT_PAYAMOUNT="4525" DEBIT_PAYAMOUNT_DATE="07 Apr 2017" DEPOSITCHARGE="0" DEPOSITPAID="0" DUEDATE="08 May 2017" EMAILID="bhadrinath@circles.asia" EXADJUSTEDAMOUNT="0" EXDEPOSIT="0" EXDISCOUNT="0" EXDISCOUNTABLE="4205" EXDISCOUNTED="0" EXLATEPAYMENTAMOUNT="0" EXPREVIOUSBALANCEAMOUNT="0" EXPREVIOUSBILLAMOUNT="4525" EXPREVIOUSCREDITAMOUNT="0" EXPREVIOUSDEBITAMOUNT="0" EXPREVIOUSPAYMENTAMOUNT="4525" EXROUNDEDAMOUNT="0" EXROUNDINGAMOUNT="0" EXSUBTOTAL="3971" EXSURCHARGE="0" EXTAX="234" EXTAXABLE="0" EXTOTALAMOUNT="4205" EXTOTALDUE="4205" EXTOTALEARLYPAYMENTAMOUNT="0" EXTOTALLATEPAYMENTAMOUNT="4205" EXTOTALUNROUNDEDBILLAMOUNT="0" FORMATPATTERN="#,##0.00" FROMDATE="01 Apr 2017" GST="234" HOME_IC_AMOUNT="0" HOME_IC_MIN="0" HOME_OG_AMOUNT="759.5" HOME_OG_MIN="6" HOME_USAGE_VOICE_AMOUNT="0" HOME_USAGE_VOICE_MIN="0" IDD_BUDGET_AMOUNT="0" IDD_BUDGET_MIN="0" IDD_BUDGET_SEC="0" IDD_NORMAL_AMOUNT="760" IDD_NORMAL_MIN="5" IDD_NORMAL_SEC="54" IDD_USAGE_SMS_AMOUNT="0" IDD_USAGE_SMS_COUNT="0" IMG=" " INVOICENUMBER="REG0000001377872" LASTBILLDATE="01 Apr 2017" LOCALMMSAMOUNT="0" LOCALMMSCOUNT="0" LOCALSMSAMOUNT="0" LOCALSMSCOUNT="0" LOCALVOICEAMOUNTUSED="0" LOCALVOICEMINUSED="0" LOCAL_USAGE_AMOUNT="0" LOCAL_USAGE_DATA_VOLUME="6.92" LOCAL_USAGE_MMS_AMOUNT="0" LOCAL_USAGE_MMS_COUNT="0" LOCAL_USAGE_SMS_AMOUNT="0" LOCAL_USAGE_SMS_COUNT="0" LWACCOUNTNUMBER="LW555358" LWBILLDATE="01 May 2017" LWFORMATPATTERN="#,##0.00" LWMINORUNIT="2" LWTOTALTAXEXEMPTION="604.55" MAJORNAME="SGD" MAJORSYMBOL="$" MINORUNIT="2" MOBILENO="87423009" NAME="BHADRINATH RAMACHANDRAN" NONRECCHARGE="0" OC_AMOUNT="0" ONETIMEAMOUNT="0" PLUSAMOUNT="200" PLUS_AMOUNT="200" PREVIOUSBILLAMOUNT="4525" PRE_BASE_AMOUNT="0" PRE_BASE_DATA="3" PRE_BASE_SMS="0" PRE_BASE_VOICE="0" PRE_COMPONENT_DATA="1" PRE_COMPONENT_DATA_AMOUNT="0" PRE_COMPONENT_SMS="0" PRE_COMPONENT_SMS_AMOUNT="0" PRE_COMPONENT_VOICE="0" PRE_COMPONENT_VOICE_AMOUNT="0" PROADDONDATAAMOUNT="0" PROADDONDATAQUOTA="1" PROADDONSMSAMOUNT="0" PROADDONSMSQUOTA="0" PROADDONVOICEAMOUNT="0" PROADDONVOICEQUOTA="0" PROBASEAMOUNT="0" PROBASEDATAQUOTA="3" PROBASESMSQUOTA="0" PROBASEVOICEQUOTA="0" PROBONUSQUOTA="4.2" PRS_AMOUNT="0" RECCHARGE="3365" RECFIXRECCHARGE="0" ROAMING_USAGE_AMOUNT="0" SMSIDDAMOUNT="0" SMSROAMAMOUNT="0" SMS_ROAMING_AMOUNT="0" SMS_ROAMING_COUNT="0" SPECIAL_USAGE_AMOUNT="759.5" STATENAME="Singapore" TODATE="30 Apr 2017" TOTALCREDIT="0" TOTALDEBIT="0" TOTALTAXEXEMPTION="604.55" TXT="Please login to www.example.com to pay your bill." UNLIMITEDICCALLSAMOUNT="0" USAGECHARGE="606" USERNAME="BHADRINATH RAMACHANDRAN" VOICEIDDAMOUNT="759.5" VOICEROAMAMOUNT="0" VOICE_ROAMING_AMOUNT="0" ZIP="310231"/><multiplerecord type="LW_CALL_DETAIL">
  <record CALLDATETIME="10 Apr 2017 - 22:44" CALLSECTION="VOICEIDD" CALLTYPE="Outgoing" COUNTRY="India" DURATIONMIN="1" DURATIONSEC="0" PHONENO="919444281907" RATE="150" REFUNDEXISTS="N" USAGEAMOUNT="150" USAGEKB="0" USAGEMB="0"/>
  <record CALLDATETIME="19 Apr 2017 - 06:37" CALLSECTION="VOICEIDD" CALLTYPE="Outgoing" COUNTRY="Philippines" DURATIONMIN="1" DURATIONSEC="0" PHONENO="639175620965" RATE="90" REFUNDEXISTS="N" USAGEAMOUNT="90" USAGEKB="0" USAGEMB="0"/>
  <record CALLDATETIME="24 Apr 2017 - 16:31" CALLSECTION="VOICEIDD" CALLTYPE="Outgoing" COUNTRY="HongKong" DURATIONMIN="1" DURATIONSEC="0" PHONENO="85239704983" RATE="70.0000000000000000000000000000000000002" REFUNDEXISTS="N" USAGEAMOUNT="70" USAGEKB="0" USAGEMB="0"/>
  <record CALLDATETIME="25 Apr 2017 - 18:16" CALLSECTION="VOICEIDD" CALLTYPE="Outgoing" COUNTRY="India" DURATIONMIN="1" DURATIONSEC="54" PHONENO="918861871977" RATE="155" REFUNDEXISTS="N" USAGEAMOUNT="294.5" USAGEKB="0" USAGEMB="0"/>
  <record CALLDATETIME="28 Apr 2017 - 09:37" CALLSECTION="VOICEIDD" CALLTYPE="Outgoing" COUNTRY="India" DURATIONMIN="1" DURATIONSEC="0" PHONENO="919444281907" RATE="155" REFUNDEXISTS="N" USAGEAMOUNT="155" USAGEKB="0" USAGEMB="0"/></multiplerecord></custominfo>
```

Sample data source

Comment: Usually you would set the band height quite small and set it to stretch with overflowing content.

Comment: @mkl Yes I can do that but issue is if I set band height too small than jarsper compilation will fail as component in it will be out of band height. Note I'm using iReport for this there is no code for it.

Comment: @mkl before giving negative point first understand the issue.

Comment: You could also use 1 band per list and make them conditional, i.e. only show them if you know there are entries for the list.

Comment: And the downvote was not from me, neither were the close votes. Usually those commenting on issues here are those who try to make the question answerable, while those downvote who immediately give up on it.

Comment: Issue is both the list must be in same frame for design purpose

Comment: Please add such information to your question. Probably you should share an example jrxml to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Attached source please check

Comment: I don't have any data to put in there but with both lists empty the data box hardly contains more than the title. Can you share a sample dataset which illustrates the issue? Furthermore, I use JR 6.3.1, which version do you use?

Comment: added sample datasource

Comment: Running your jrxml template against your sample data results in something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p20Xk.png). Which "white blanks" do you mean?

Comment: I'm using version 5.6, which gives space between two frames

Comment: So that appears to be a bug which meanwhile has been fixed. Thus, you should update.

Comment: 5.6 version of iReport let me correct that

Comment: Most likely iReport 5.6 is backed by JasperReports 5.6.

Comment: So what could be the possible solution for this ?

Comment: Updating. iReport unfortunately has been discontinued at version 6 but there now is Jaspersoft Studio as a replacement.

Comment: Oh well will try doing this hopefully it works.thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasper version 5.6 has some bug which doesn't allow band height decrease automatically but after updating to 6.3.1 issue seems fixed and band height changes dynamically.